# Parent is not public in Component

Tags: java, mysql, authentication

I have two syntax error in my login form panel code and here is it :

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       boolean result =false;
    try{ Koneksi objKoneksi = new Koneksi();
        Connection kon = objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi();
        Statement stat = kon.createStatement();
        String username = id.getText();
        String password = pass.getText();


        String query = "select * from userid where id='" +id+ "'and pass='"+pass+"'";

            result=stat.executeQuery(query).next();
       } catch (SQLException e)   
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());}
       if(result){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LOGIN SUCCESS");
           this.setVisible(false);
           new Aplikasi().show();
           this.parent.setVisible(true);
           this.dispose();}
       else {
           error.setText("ERROR LOGIN");}             

}
```

There is a Strikethrough on `Show()` method and a red balloon in the line `this.parent.setVisible(true)` said `Parent is not public in Component; cannot be accessed from outside packages.`
What could go wrong here?
thanks before

PS: I'm newbie and English is not my Native Language

Answer (score 0):

A strike through most likely means that the method you are calling is deprecated.

The error saying parent is not public means that the field `parent` in `this` object cannot be accessed directly. If I'm not wrong you can call `getParent()` to get access to it.

Comment: so what's the new one for `show()` ? I try to run file, and it shows ERROR LOGIN (i've already add my userid and password to database)

Comment: You will probably need to check your documentation of the `Aplikasi` class, or its parent classes to see why `show()` gives you the strike through. BTW, the strike through is probably added by your IDE, so you should also check your IDE help/doc to see what exactly it means as well just to be sure.

Comment: I got the Show() problem covered. What about the error login?